# Linked Access table to ODBC Database doesn't show all columns

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ms-access-2013, linked-tables

I am creating a database in Access 2013.

I need to create a few tables that are linked to a SQL Server that other Access queries will use to get data. No information will be returned to the SQL Server, the tables are for information only.

I tried using a pass-through query to SQL Server, which worked except that I couldn't refresh it, I had to go back to 'SQL View' and click 'Run'. I did some research and found that pass-through queries are not updateable. If someone could prove that wrong I would be glad!!

I then tried to create a linked table to SQL Server, however it only showed 22 columns (all of which happen to be totally useless to me) out of 267 columns (don't worry, I only need about 3 or 4 of those columns).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: 267 columns in a single table? Sounds like some normalization should done soon. Aside from that your question is a bit confusing. Are you using a link table via a view in sql server?

Comment: Yes, it contains most of the information about all of our parts.

Comment: I tried creating a linked table in access to a table in our company's database on SQL server.  Does that help or not?  I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: When you say pass through sql I assume you mean you are running a query against sql server? If that is the case, why do you need a link table? Can't you just create a connection to sql and run your query there?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I did, but then I cannot refresh it

Comment: What do you mean you can't refresh it?

Comment: I get an error that says it can't find the file, with the filename being the database table i specified in my 'FROM' statement

Comment: File??? Are you making a connection to your sql server? It sounds like you are running an Access query.

Comment: I still think that 267 columns is ridiculous, especially for a table of parts. It sounds like you need to have a number of additional tables to get your parts normalized.

Comment: Exactly, I can't figure out why it's looking for a file.  I have entered all the necessary info in the 'Connection String' field and it doesn't seem to be looking at that.

Comment: Two things, I have no authority over how our database is set up (or how many columns it has) and whether it's ridiculous or not has nothing to do with my question.  I only mentioned it in case there was some sort of limit on creating a linked table

Comment: Offering some advice in the hope it would be met with an opportunity to learn better ways. I realize it had nothing to do with your question. Back to your current issue, can you share some code so I can see what you are trying to do? It seems like you are making a link table when querying sql directly is likely a better option.

Comment: The sample SQL code I wrote when I was testing this out (I will be making it significantly more complex once I get this issue figured out) was `SELECT item.item, item.description FROM Syteline_MTL_PROD_App.dbo.item item ORDER BY item.item`  "Syteline_MTL_PROD_App" is the database, "dbo.item" is the table and  "item" and "description" are column names

Comment: That's really weird, I am no longer getting any errors.  I don't believe I have changed anything!?

Comment: *"I tried using a pass-through query to SQL Server, which worked except that I couldn't refresh it, I had to go back to 'SQL View' and click 'Run'."* - That's odd, because [F5] (Refresh All) does in fact refresh (requery) a pass-through query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't exactly know why I was getting errors, but I am no longer having problems with this.